# Pivot two columns keeping corresponding ids programmatically

Tags: sql, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with the following structure

```
ID    Category    Value
1        Age        23
1      Income     10000
2        Age        30
2      Income     50000
```

I would like to pivot it so that there is one row per id

```
ID      Age   Income
1       23     10000
2       30     50000
```

I am not sure if its possible in Snowflake DB.

EDIT: the actual table has 206 levels in the category factor, so I am looking for a programmatic way without needing to reference category levels in the query.

Comment: And when you search "sql pivot" you don't get any results on Google?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did find methods using decode or case as snowflake does not support the pivot function. I am struggling with coming up with SQL that keeps ids corresponding to the two pivoted columns.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should give you what you need by using the CASE statement:

```
SELECT ID,
CASE WHEN Category = 'Age' THEN Value END as 'Age',
CASE WHEN Category = 'Income' THEN Value END as 'Income'
FROM TABLENAME
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for a table with two unique levels for the category column. However, my actual table has 206 levels in category column. I could generate the query using python and the level names unless there is  a programmatic way.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Without the pivot function available I can't see how to achieve this programmatically.  I presume the 206 levels could change over time as well.

Comment: Even with PIVOT, you would need to explicitly specify which values you need to convert to columns. I am not aware of a system that could do this automatically. So writing a query that generates the final query (e.g. in Python) might be the only way to go.

Comment: You could use a dynamic SQL pivot to achieve without explicitly specifying the values, but pivot is still not going to work in this case. I was thinking it must be possible using cursors and came across this: https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/ It doesn't give the exact answer but may point to an appropriate approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Age' THEN Value END) as Age,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Income' THEN Value END) as Income
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY ID;
```